# Count number of rows that are not NA

Tags: r, dataframe, count, rows

So I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
"date","id_station","id_parameter","valor","unit","year","day","month","hour","zona"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"AJM","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"ATI","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"BJU","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"CE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"CAM","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"CCA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"CHO","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"CUA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"FAC","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"HGM","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"CE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"IZT","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"CE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"LLA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"LPR","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"MER","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"CE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"MGH","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"NEZ","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"PED","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"SAG","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"SFE","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"SJA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"TAH","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"TLA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"TLI","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NO"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"UAX","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"UIZ","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"SE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"VIF","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NE"
2019-01-01 00:00:00,"XAL","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,0,"NE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"AJM","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"ATI","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"BJU","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"CE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"CAM","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"CCA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"CHO","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"CUA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"FAC","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"HGM","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"CE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"IZT","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"CE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"LLA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"LPR","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"MER","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"CE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"MGH","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"NEZ","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"PED","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"SAG","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"SFE","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"SJA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"TAH","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"TLA","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"TLI","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NO"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"UAX","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"UIZ","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"SE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"VIF","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NE"
2019-01-01 01:00:00,"XAL","CO",NA,15,2019,1,1,1,"NE"
```

And what I want to do is to group all based on id_station, id_parameter, year, day, and month. Afterwards, I want to count the number of rows that are not NA in "valor" for each day.

**Finally, I want to determine how many days had at least 18 non-NA values for each day of each id_station. If there are less than 274 days, I want to delete ALL values associated to that id_station**

How can I do this?

Comment: If you have a new question, use the ask question button. Do not add new requirements to an existing question. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274958/chameleon-question-changed-from-one-duplicate-to-another) for more info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After grouping by the columns of interest, get the `sum` of logical vector as the count i.e. - `is.na(valor)` returns a logical vector with TRUE where there are NA and FALSE for non-NA, negate (`!`) to reverse it and get the `sum` of the logical such as each TRUE (`-> 1`) represents one non-NA element

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id_station, id_parameter, year, day, month) %>%
    summarise(Count = sum(!is.na(valor)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option might be

```
aggregate(
    cbind(Count = !is.na(valor)) ~id_station + id_parameter + year + day + month,
    df,
    sum
)
```